# How to ignore accents (À Â É Ê etc.) when sorting?

Tags: text-editing, unicode, formatting, sorting, locale

When sorting text with Emacs, the result is wrong for accented characters:

```
Always
Emerald
Yesterday
Zoo
À la campagne
Âge
Écarlate
Être
```

Here is the result I would like instead:

```
À la campagne
Âge
Always
Écarlate
Emerald
Être
Yesterday
Zoo
```

How can I sort these special characters as regular letters, that is, ignoring the accents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`sort-lines`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sorting.html#index-sort_002dlines) calls [`compare-buffer-substrings`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Comparing-Text.html#index-compare_002dbuffer_002dsubstrings) to compare lines, and it isn't locale-aware. If you want to sort lines and you're on a Unix-like platform (basically anything except Windows, or Windows with basic Unix-like tools available), you can use the external [`sort`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html) command through [`shell-command-on-region`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Single-Shell.html#index-shell_002dcommand_002don_002dregion) (`M-|`), with a prefix argument to indicate that you want to replace the region by the output of the command:

```
ESC 1 ESC | LC_COLLATE=fr_FR.utf8 sort RET
```

If your ambient locale already sets your preferred collation order, then you can directly type

```
ESC 1 ESC | sort RET
```

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your locale, you can try

```
    (sort 
     '("Always" "Emerald" "Yesterday" "Zoo" "À la campagne" "Âge" "Écarlate" "Être") 
 #'string-collate-lessp) 
=>
("Âge" "À la campagne" "Always" "Écarlate" "Emerald" "Être" "Yesterday" "Zoo")
```